# using search firstname and last name mixed php query

Tags: php, sql, search, output

I have a SQL query command.  The problem is when I type the whole name of a person it won't appear. For example if I search for "ermel", it will show ermel. However, when I search for "ermel lopez" it will fail to output the query.  Here's my query:

```
      $query=mysql_query("select * from persons where firstname like '%$searchtext%' or lastname like   '%$searchtext%' order by date desc
      LIMIT $start,$per_page ");
```

I tried `CONCAT`, which works, but won't work on the executable:

```
 SELECT *  
 FROM   persons 
 WHERE  CONCAT( firstname,  ' ', lastname ) LIKE 'kaitlyn' 
 OR     `LastName` LIKE  'pineda' 
 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reversing the way you check your strings like this:

```
"select * from persons 
where '$searchtext' like concat('%',firstname,'%') 
   or '$searchtext' like concat('%',lastname,'%')
 order by date desc
LIMIT $start,$per_page "
```

This should result in a match on your searchtext containing either the firstname or lastname.

Comment: it's working sir the only problem is if i search for example . i search ermel it won't show but if i search full name ermel lopez it will show? thankss one more question how can i make it so that if the user put keywords it will accept it like the original query i posted @McSenstrum

Comment: If FirstName=ermal and LastName = lopez, then my query should find a match on searchtext 'ermal','lopez', or 'ermal lopez'.
It will also find a match on 'ermal garcia' or 'juan lopez'. it's simply any record where the search text contains any matching first or last name.

Comment: yes can i use this to find a keyword only in the firstname and lastname and if i want i can search also firstname and lastname like on your answer? :D

Comment: here's my new question . with screen shots to make it easier :D [link for the question]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239282/php-search-result-output-different-result-if-you-give-one-letter-only @McSenstrum

Answer (score 0):

a LIKE without wildcards is an exact match!
you need
Like 'kaitlyn%'

Comment: the kaitlyn and pinede is the result i replace it with '%$searchtext%' on the form

Answer (score 0):

I think your Sql Query is wrong
when you search Full name (ermel lopez)
Then from your query, you search it in both columns.
But whole text is not stored in a columns

Try this

$searchtext1="ermel";

$searchtext2= "lopez";

`$query=mysql_query("select * from persons where firstname like '%$searchtext1%' or lastname like   '%$searchtext2%' order by date desc
      LIMIT $start,$per_page ");`

Comment: so it's not possible to do it can i use unite in it so firstname and lastname will combine in a temporary row like the `show * from persons as result` like that? @user2320325